# How to get € to appear correctly on a web page?

Tags: html

The euro `€` symbols in the footer of this page are not displaying correctly

http://fundcentre.newireland.ie/

What is the best way to correct this?

**Edit:** this html is supplied by a 3rd party. We take it, wrap it around our content, and render the page

**Edit Again:** just looking at the code, I can see that we read the 3rd party HTML into our solution with the following:

`wrapperHtml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sWrapperLocation, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));` .. So we're reading it as one encoding and rendering it as the other..

Comment: That seems to be a general encoding problem. The footer also has some broken characters. Note that replacing it by the entity is *not* the right fix. You should add more details about where that data comes from. Does it come from a database?

Comment: you should show or describe the code you're using to fetch it from that 3rd party, and add the necessary server side tags (from your page's source I gather it's ASP.NET).

Comment: @Pekka, yeah it's ASP.NET (and on that note, I apologise 'cause it's the worst HTML I have ever seen. I didn't write it!!). I think the code that fetches it from the 3rd party is fine because the symbols render fine when I load the wrapper without our content. Maybe it's the way we're injecting our content into it that's causing the problem. I'll have a look at that.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure because I don't know what comes from where, but try changing `iso-8859-1` to `utf-8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like UTF-8 data that was somehow interpreted in a ISO-8859-1 context (or some other single byte encoding). Whatever you use to read the 3rd party source may be incorrectly interpreting the data as single-byte while it in fact is UTF-8.

This is about everything that can be said without knowing more about your setup.

**Edit:** Why fixing this by using entities is a bad idea, copied from my comment:

The problem is not limited to the Euro character, but applies to all characters outside the ISO-8859-1 range. That means that while you can happily replace the € by € without any real damage, the instant a chinese or cyrillic character comes up in your data, you'll have no entity to convert it to. You would have to convert perfectly healthy UTF-8 content into their numeric entities in real time just to avoid having to fix the encoding problem. That is just insane.

Comment: You're making sense. I've just updated the question with something I've noticed in the code.

Answer (score 0):

`&#8364;` is the entity you are looking for

Comment: The problem in question is an encoding issue. The page is using UTF-8 so there is no reason not to use the native character instead of the entity.

Comment: @trick it does work, but it's not the right fix for this specific problem. Look into the page's footer, there are more broken characters than just the euro.

Comment: Pekka - Its a .net site and as such has encoding issues. Depending on how the file is saved (depending on the editor used in windows - including WebDeveloper and its options) and how it is transfered up to the server can muck up the UTF-8 encoding. When I develop, I always use html encoding to mitigate these issues.

Comment: but maybe the data come from a iso database, and the conversion doesn't get well

Comment: If the data is from database or any other source the encoding may already be mucked up. asp.net has functions to html encode text for output, but the input has to be correct for it to work at all.

Comment: @Justin I know what you mean, but it is almost always possible to set up the workflow so encodings don't get mucked up, which is much, much preferable. The only exception to that that I know is when dealing with 3rd party data with changing encodings.

Comment: @Pekka - If you can control the workflow, then yes thats great. but chances are he can't. I've developed sites where Microsoft Web Developer just decides to on a whim change the encoding of a file when saved, so even if the site workflow is setup, I tend not to trust the encoding to "Just Work" and I encode it all :)

Comment: @Justin808 I'm from the PHP world so I don't know those tools, but I can't believe that it's impossible for a ASP.NET dev to reliably control a file's encoding in 2011 - I have a PHP IDE that does the same thing that you describe, but when I notice it, I have to change it. I maintain: Entities are a dirty fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML encoding; to get a € type a `&euro;`

Comment: If you are just going to make down an answer, post why you are. The html encoding would solve his display issues. If he encoded all the characters, it would all all his display issues. This is a valid answer.

Comment: @Justin I downvoted all answers suggesting using the entity, because the issue at hand is most likely a solvable encoding problem. Using the entity instead of that underlying problem is a dirty fix.

Comment: @Pekka, we disagree - html encoding is a valid fix and solves the issue, regardless if its hard coded, or encoded via asp.net function. Changing the encoding of the file as stored on disk may or may not be possible; and is another valid answer, but that does not change the fact that html ecoding is valid. Please mark down incorrect answers, not just ones that you disagree with :)

Comment: @Justin believe me, this is not a workable fix. The problem is not limited to the Euro character, but applies to *all characters outside the ISO-8859-1 range.* That means that while you can happily replace the `€` by `&euro;` without any real damage, the instant a chinese or cyrillic character comes up in your data, you'll have no entity to convert it to. You would have to convert perfectly healthy UTF-8 content into their numeric entities *in real time* just to avoid having to fix the encoding problem. That is just insane.

Comment: @Pekka - Trust me I've written a fully multi-lingual CMS in c#. Yes if you have UTF-8 from a trusted source and can output it, great. But thats not always possible. The link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx describes a function to html encode on the fly which helps a lot form un-trusted sources. 

I do understand you disagree, really I do, you can even think using html encoding in insane - but its still a valid way to get the characters to display correctly. And in all honesty, with asp.net, its probably the fastest and easiest way. Yes, I agree, not the *best* way.

Comment: @Justin but that HtmlEncode method won't work if you don't know the source encoding, will it? If you don't know the incoming data's encoding, you'll have to guess or force the source to tell you.  HTML encoding can not turn arbitrary data with an unknown encoding into readable data. And, and this is my argument, if you *know* (or are able to guess) the incoming encoding, you can just as well convert it to proper UTF-8, which is much preferable - and in cases of chinese and cyrillic text, also a huge space saver.

Comment: @Pekka - My understanding is it does a best guess (which tends to be better than a browsers best guess). Based on what Dave said, if he is getting the information from somewhere else and wrapping it in his page format, and its like that, the encoding is mucked up before he gets it. He'll either have to fix how he is getting is, or use find/replace to fix it the hard way. Sometimes the *best* way to do things just isn't an option.

Comment: @Justin I have nothing against dirty fixes when there's no other option left. But suggesting the dirty fix before checking whether it's necessary at all and no caveat that it's a dirty fix is no good, that's my whole point. It seems like the encoding *is* controllable after all, see OP's update

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
wrapperHtml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sWrapperLocation, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Try changing it to:

```
wrapperHtml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sWrapperLocation, System.Text.UTF8Encoding);
```

That should keep the multi-byte characters correctly.

**Edit:**
Also you could just remove the second argument all together as that will keep the original encoding regardless of what it was.

**Update:**
I know its evil, but try this. If it works, the encoding issue is on your end, somewhere, if it doesn't work the encoding issue is with the file or where you get the file.

```
wrapperHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sWrapperLocation));
```

The above line will trap and encode the multi-byte and single byte characters that need to be for html encoding. For the moment it will take encoding issues off the plate if they are in your code (after this line), with the server, with the transport or with the browser, with the doc types and a lot of other things. If it works, you know the file is in a valid format and your encoding issues are somewhere after the file and you reading in the file.

Comment: Hi Justin, unfortunately none of these worked. I've even tried reading a simple text file which contains only a € symbol. It gets read in as a '?'

Comment: @Dave did you try removing the second argument completely as well?

Comment: @Pekka, yes - there's something odd going on!!

Comment: @Dave - let me know if the update I posed works, even with only some of the characters.

Answer (score -1):

Use HTML code : `&#8364;` or `&euro;`